# Mounting EFS With AWS Ubuntu

Tags: mount, nfs, amazon-ec2, aws

I am trying to mount my Elastic File System (EFS) on an EC2 instance in the same availability zone.  However, `mount` just hangs and eventually says `Connection timed out`.  The AWS docs say that I must configure my security groups to allow traffic on TCP 2049, the NFS port.  However, even when I allow outbound 2049 traffic from the instance, inbound 2049 traffic on the EFS, and my Network ACLs allow inbound/outbound traffic on all ephemeral ports (TCP 1024-65535), I still cannot successfully mount the EFS.

I read on [this post](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/5123/) that NFS also uses ports TCP/UDP 111 and 1110. If so, why don't the AWS docs mention these ports, and what should my new Security Group / Network ACL rules be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my Network ACLs allow inbound/outbound traffic on all ephemeral ports (TCP 1024-65535)

That's the problem -- these rules are not going to be enough.

The Linux NFS client uses a privileged *source* port (<1024) for outbound connections by default, instead of an ephemeral port. (See `netstat -a -n | grep 2049` while waiting for the timeout.)

Some NFS servers require the client to use a privileged port to originate the connection, but EFS doesn't.

So, add `-o noresvport` to your mount command and you should have no issue.

Note also that EFS does not require any other open ports -- only TCP 2049 toward the EFS endpoint.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Adding "-o noresvport" fixed it!  So are you saying that I should get rid of my ACL rules that allow ephemeral ports? Adding "-o noresvport" works even with these rules set, and according to the docs, I needs these rules to allow SSH access and HTTPS traffic.

Comment: Also, I'm now getting the error "special device us-east-1a.fs-1768925e.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/ does not exist"  even though I've verified that this is the correct DNS for the EFS mount target.  Any ideas on this?

Comment: I'm not saying block the ephemeral ports.  I updated the answer to try to clarify that.  Adding `-o noresvport` tells the client to use an ephemeral port.

Comment: Wait... I thought you said this was fixed, but now you say you get an error? What changed?  Show your entire mount command.

Comment: OK, the edited answer makes more sense, thanks again for your time on this. The "does not exist" error is actually happening when I try to modify /etc/fstab and mount automatically. Mounting manually works fine. My mount command was "sudo mount -t nfs -o vers=4.1,noresvport us-east-1a.fs-1768925e.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/ myDir", and again it works without issue (verified by checking /etc/mtab). The line that I'm adding to the fstab is "us-east-1a.fs-1768925e.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/ myDir xfs defaults,vers=4.1,noresvport 0 0" and then I run "sudo mount -a -t nfs", giving the error

Comment: Oh wow, I see what I did.  The fstab line was using `xfs` when it should've been using `nfs`.  Case closed.  Thanks for the excellent help @Michael!